# JsonConvert.Deserializer indexing issues

Tags: c#, stack, json.net

While playing around Stack collection in C# I encountered the following issue. Exactly I am not sure why it is happening. Please put some light on the reason and alternative to the solution.

Problem -

A class having Stack as property. For example name that class as Progress. T is of class type Item.

Now whenever the user makes any progress we will be storing in stack. And if user leaves in between, then next time we will peek the item from the stack so from that stage. Below code snippet will give an idea of what is being tried...

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StackCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Progress progress = new Progress();

            progress.Items.Push(new Item { PlanID = null, PlanName = "Plan A" });

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(progress);
            var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString);

            temp.Items.Push(new Item { PlanID = null, PlanName = "Plan B" });

            jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
            temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString);

            temp.Items.Push(new Item { PlanID = null, PlanName = "Plan C" });

            jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
            temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString);

            WriteLine(temp.Items.Peek().PlanName);

            ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Progress
    {
        public Stack<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public Progress()
        {
            Items = new Stack<Item>();
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string PlanID { get; set; }

        public string PlanName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now the line -

```
WriteLine(temp.Items.Peek().PlanName);
```

should return

> Plan C

but it is returning

> Plan B

So, why the index is being changed, any clue or pointer will be helpful.

Comment: Also few investigations shows, the JSON string is having correct sequence, but after the last 
temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString);
the index shuffles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the stack is being serialized as a List. The problem is that this does not preserve the proper order when deconstructing the stack (the items are actually pushed in the reverse order). Here's a quick workaround to this issue:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StackCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Progress progress = new Progress();

            progress.Items.Push(new Item { PlanID = null, PlanName = "Plan A" });

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(progress);
            var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString);

            temp.Items.Push(new Item { PlanID = null, PlanName = "Plan B" });

            jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
            temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString);

            temp.Items.Push(new Item { PlanID = null, PlanName = "Plan C" });

            jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
            temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString);

            WriteLine(temp.Items.Peek().PlanName);

            ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Progress
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Stack<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }

        [OnSerializing]
        internal void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            ItemList = Items?.ToList();
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            ItemList?.Reverse();
            Items = new Stack<Item>(ItemList ?? Enumerable.Empty<Item>());
        }

        public Progress()
        {
            Items = new Stack<Item>();
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string PlanID { get; set; }

        public string PlanName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes agreed the items are pushed in reverse order. Let me try the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a known behavior of Json.NET, as noted by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39137220/3744182), a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) can be used when deserializing a stack that pushes items on in the correct order.

The following universal converter can be used with `Stack<T>` for any `T`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converter for any Stack<T> that prevents Json.NET from reversing its order when deserializing.
/// </summary>
public class StackConverter : JsonConverter
{
    // Prevent Json.NET from reversing the order of a Stack<T> when deserializing.
    // https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/971
    static Type StackParameterType(Type objectType)
    {
        while (objectType != null)
        {
            if (objectType.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genericType = objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genericType == typeof(Stack<>))
                    return objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
            objectType = objectType.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return StackParameterType(objectType) != null;
    }

    object ReadJsonGeneric<T>(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(reader);
        var stack = existingValue as Stack<T> ?? (Stack<T>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            stack.Push(list[i]);
        return stack;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            var parameterType = StackParameterType(objectType);
            var method = GetType().GetMethod("ReadJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { parameterType });
            return genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            // Wrap the TargetInvocationException in a JsonSerializerException
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Failed to deserialize " + objectType, ex);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then add it to `JsonSerializerSettings` to correct the ordering of stacks when deserializing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new StackConverter() } };
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(progress, settings);
var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Progress>(jsonString, settings);
```

Or mark the `Stack<T>` property directly with [`[JsonConverter(typeof(StackConverter))]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm):

```
class Progress
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StackConverter))]
    public Stack<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Progress()
    {
        Items = new Stack<Item>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try to debug it then you will notice that items order is broken after `Stack` deserialization.

The same question [has been asked](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/971) on JSON.NET GitHub issue tracker a month ago.

The answer from JamesNK:

> I'm afraid this is a limition of a Stack. The results returned when it is serialized and the opposite order for when it is deserialized.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, 1 more observation, in Stack when ever an item is pushed it is pushed to index 0.
so when we run for loop like
foreach(var item in _temp)
{
it starts popping in LIFO
}

but when we deserialize using JSONConvert, I think it tries to deserialize as Queue - FIFO. 
Not sure just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019, this C# works:

```
List<string> ls = null;
Stack<string> ss = null;
if (json != null)
{
    ls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
    ss = new Stack<string>(ls);
}
```

(This is an edit of the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030973/json-deserialization-with-stack-structure-reverses-order), which originally had an errant Reverse method call on the list that caused the opposite of the desired result.)