# Deserialization of Stack<>

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize an object that contains a property of type `Stack<T>`:

```
public class Card
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Game 
{
   public Stack<Card> Cards { get; } = new Stack<Card>();
}

var game = new Game();
game.Cards.Push(new Card() { Name = "Whatever" });
string ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(game);
Game unser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(ser);
```

When I try to deserialize an object previously serialized, the Cards-Property contains an **empty** Stack.

The missing setter is not the issue. When I change the `Stack<>` to `List<>` deserializing works:

```
public class Game 
{
    public List<Card> Cards { get; } = new List<Card>();
}
var game = new Game();
game.Cards.Add(new Card() { Name = "Whatever"));
string ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(game);
Game unser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(ser);
```

So the same works fine  when using a `List<>`, but not a `Stack<>`

So my questions are:

1. Why :)
2. Can I force Json.NET to work with `Stack<>`?

*As dbc already showed, this is not a duplicate. The issue is not a wrong direction of the entries, but the entries completely missing.*

Comment: Does this code even compile? You have two types in your property definition `string Stack<Card> Cards {get;}`. Is it a string or a Stack?

Comment: Sorry. Typo. Corrected

Comment: Related (but possibly not a perfect duplicate, need to check): [JsonConvert.Deserializer indexing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39137123/3744182)... OK, I think `StackConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39481981/3744182) should work for you since it uses the existing value if present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonConvert.Deserializer indexing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137123/jsonconvert-deserializer-indexing-issues)

Comment: @dbc Looks like a good answer for me. Still I am surprised, that in the linked question the issue wasn't that the deserializing completely failed, but it was returned in the wrong order. I am curious if the Json-behavior changed in the last two years.

Comment: @OleAlbers - actually there's an additional problem.  Will write something up soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue using Json.NET to deserialize `Stack<T>` which is explained in

- [JsonConvert.Deserializer indexing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39137123/3744182).
- [Issue #971: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stack<T>>`/`JsonConvert.Serialize(Stack<T)` does not work as expected.](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/971)
- [Issue #1654: Elements reversed in serializing and deserializing a Stack](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1654).

The behavior reported is that `Stack<T>` is *reversed* on deserialization, and the suggested solution is to use a custom `JsonConverter` such as the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39481981/3744182).

Unfortunately it appears that solution does not work for a **get-only** stack property such as yours.  Even if I specify a working converter for `Stack<T>` the get-only property comes back empty.  See [.Net fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AAzEiU) for a demo of the problem.

So, why does this happen?  Because [`Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T>` but not `ICollection<T>`, the [`JsonArrayContract` constructor](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonArrayContract.cs#L115) interprets `Stack<T>` as a *read-only collection* that must be constructed via its [parameterized constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76atxd68.aspx).  Then, later, when attempting to deserialize your get-only, pre-allocated `Stack<T>` property, [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.CalculatePropertyDetails()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1036) decides the pre-existing value cannot be used (because it's a read-only collection) and since a newly allocated collection cannot be set back (because the property is not writable) the JSON property must be **skipped**.  This, of course, doesn't account for the possibility that a `JsonConverter` if present might be able to populate the collection somehow, even though Json.NET cannot.

This feels like a bug to me; you might [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) to Newtonsoft that a get-only `Stack<T>` property cannot be deserialized even with a custom `JsonConverter`.

As a workaround that preserves the immutability of your `Stack<T>` property, in addition to creating a custom `JsonConverter` for `Stack<T>`, you can create a parameterized constructor for your `Game` that takes a `Stack<Card> cards` argument, and mark it with [`JsonConstructor`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConstructorAttribute):

```
public class Game 
{
    public Game() { this.cards =  new Stack<Card>(); }

    [JsonConstructor]       
    Game(Stack<Card> cards)
    {
        this.cards = cards ??  new Stack<Card>();
    }

    readonly Stack<Card> cards;

    public Stack<Card> Cards { get { return cards; } }
}
```

Note that the constructor argument name must be the same as the JSON property name, modulo case.

(Alternatively, you could make the property be privately settable and mark it with `[JsonProperty]`; this destroys the guarantee of immutability however.)

Then to deserialize, do:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new StackConverter() },
};          
var unser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(ser, settings);
```

Where `StackConverter` is taken verbatim from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39481981/3744182).

Demo [.Net fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4GTcn) showing that the workaround does work.